# How Can I Use WebView.NavigateToString in MVVM Pattern Without Code-Behind?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, mvvm, uwp

I need my app to dynamically load and display locally stored html files at runtime.  Because of UWP sandbox, binding a WebView source to a URI will not work unless the location is in appdata.  These html files contain base64 embedded video thus are large, so copying to the Local folder each time would result in a delay from the disk write operation.

My workaround idea is to load the file into memory and use WebView.NavigateToString or WebView.NavigateToStreamUri.  But these would need to be invoked from the code-behind which of course would break the clean MVVM pattern I'm going for.  I'm not just being an MVVM purist, I want to be able to load user provided XAML files as "skins" at runtime and can't do that if I have to call these methods in the code-behind.  Are there any solutions I haven't thought of?

Comment: Sometimes it's necessary to use code-behind and using code-behind doesn't prevent you from using user-provided-runtime resources.  In fact it may be the only way

Comment: You could write an attached property -- or steal one; I'm sure I've seen a few around stack overflow. I used one last year but I can't now recall whether I wrote it or stole one.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm going to follow this: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/How-to-bind-HTML-from-a-7a6ff47c